# Re: Use regex to split string into group or sub-groups

Tags: regex

I want to use regex to split string into group or sub-groups using the special characters = . ^ $ : #

The rules are:

1. the group can be exist or not exists
2. For those group not exists, return empty
3. For those group exists, the results can be subgroups or 1 group whichever the regex is doable;
4. The delimiter must be in order by = . ^ $ : #
5. $ : does not require string followed by
6. = . ^ # must be followed by a string

Testing string

```
First element=Second=Group.Third.Grp^Fourth^Set$:#T1#Test2#B 3
```

Desired result is

- Group 1=> `First element`
- Group 2=> `=Second=Group`
- Group 3=> `.Third.Grp`
- Group 4=> `^Fourth^Set`
- Group 5=> `$`
- Group 6=> `:`
- Group 7=> `#T1#Test2#B 3`

I tried the regex in the website using https://regexr.com/.

Regex attempt #1

```
^(.+?)(\=.+)*(\..+)*(\^.+)*(\$)*(\:)*(\#.+)*$
```

This cannot capture group 3 – 7.

Regex attempt #2

```
^(.+?)(\=.+?)*(\..+?)*(\^.+?)*(\$)*(\:)*(\#.+)*$
```

This cannot capture `.Third.Grp`.

Regex attempts

I tried lookahead and lookbehind methods by applying to different group which I do not even know what it means. But no luck.

May someone point me out how it should be done.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: You don't need to escape `=`, `:`, or `#`.

Comment: If a group might not exist, make it optional with `?`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It is my habit to add escape character before special character so I do not need to remember which one need escape character. And I think * after a group means optional. I also tested in my attempt 2 ? after + to set it non-greedy.

Comment: `*` after a group means it can be repeated 0 or more times. If it's just one match or none, use `?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you quantify a capture group, it only captures the first of the repeated matches.

Use nested non-capture groups to match the repeated `.XXX` and `^XXX` elements, and put a capture group around these quantified groups to capture all of them.

```
^(.+?)((?:\=.+?)*)((?:\..+?)*)((?:\^.+?)*)(\$)*(\:)*((?:\#.+)*)$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/Gsurjs/2)

Comment: It is indeed functioning perfectly. Thank you so much for your assistance and detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The credit is to Barmar.

It works if I used the following regex.

```
^(.+?)(\=.+?)?(\..+?)?(\^.+?)?(\$)?(\:)?(\#.+)*$
```

Thank you. Barmar.